# Jqwidgets percentagewise width not working with Angular-5

Tags: css, angular5, jqwidget

I have worked with jqwidgets in jquery and width : '100%' works fine in jqxGrid. 
But in jqwidgets with Angular-5 components they are showing errors,

```
Unexpected end of expression: 100% at the end of the expression [100%] in ng:///DashboardModule/DashboardComponent.html@126:14 ("            </jqxGrid> -->
            <jqxGrid #myGrid (onFilter)="myGridOnFilter()"
```

**My dashboard.component.html file,**

```
<jqxGrid #myGrid (onFilter)="myGridOnFilter()"
              [width]="100%" [source]="dataAdapter" [columns]="columns"
              [sortable]="true" [filterable]="true"  [pageable]="true" 
              [enabletooltips]="true" [columnsresize]="true" [columnsreorder]="true" 
              [autoshowfiltericon]="true" [columnmenuopening]="columnmenuopening">
</jqxGrid>
```

Width with pixel works fine here. If I put [width]="700" it works fine but for % it's not working. I have tried with [width]='100%' and even with [width]=100%.

here is the property file of Angular components of Jqwidgets.
Link :- https://www.jqwidgets.com/angular-components-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/angular-grid-api.htm?search=width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is String, and as such should be "'100%'"

Comment: Oh man. Thank you. how can I forgot it.  It's working. I thought width = "100%" should work because basically it's a string.

Comment: true, but "" specifies that this is attribute, and the inner '' that it is a string